# SYBASE "net password encryption reqd" avalaibility

Tags: sap-ase

Hi i am using sybase developer edition, i am being unable to set {sp_configure "net password encryption reqd",1}. Do i need any license for this.

I get error message "Sybase :: How to start server created using sp_addserver"

I am using sybase 15.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll state that you need because I've the sybase 15.0.3 licenced version and the next command works:

```
exec sp_configure "net password encryption reqd", 1
```